# Build linux 4.9

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, plugins, make

when i am trying to Build Linux in build directory using `make O=<linux_build_directory> ARCH=arm Image`, so getting the errors as:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/payal/chanda/build/kernel'
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  Using /home/payal/chanda/linux-4.9 as source for kernel
  GEN     ./Makefile
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
In file included from <stdin>:1:0:
/home/payal/chanda/linux-4.9/scripts/gcc-plugins/gcc-common.h:4:22: fatal error: bversion.h: No such file or directory
 #include "bversion.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
Cannot use CONFIG_GCC_PLUGINS: your gcc installation does not support plugins, perhaps the necessary headers are missing?
make[1]: *** [gcc-plugins-check] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/payal/chanda/build/kernel'
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

Comment: Please add the output of `gcc -print-file-name=plugin`. Also, try the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: Is it resolved ??

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as yours,

and finally fixed it with this gcc plugin header packages installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5-plugin-dev
```

reference linked here:

http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1606.1/03341.html

Comment: Note that your GCC version must match the package.